# Is there any way to make virtual C++ methods visually distinct from non-virtual methods in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Qt Creator uses *italic font* for virtual methods. I find this feature useful. Any alternatives in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: @SidS thanks for the tip